# "hadoop fs -copyFromLocal" is not working

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I try to copy one file from my local system to `hdfs` (single node cluster) using this command:

```
hadoop fs -copyFromLocal /home/hduser/TestEmp.txt  /test
```

It gives me message like:

> WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable copyFromLocal: file /test/TestEmp.txt.*COPYING* on client 127.0.0.1.

But when I checked in `/test`, I didn't find anything there.

Why?

Comment: This is warning message.  How you are copying data,can you cross check your steps once again?

Comment: Looks like you don't have test directory available in your hadoop file system. Can you do `hdfs dfs -ls /` and send the result.

Comment: drwxr-xr-x   - hduser supergroup          0 2015-05-28 16:13 /test

Comment: Run the command: `hdfs namenode -format`

then try to copy data again. If still facing issue,share screen shot.
We want to see how you are doing.

Comment: 15/05/28 16:55:14 INFO namenode.FSImage: Allocated new BlockPoolId: BP-1557757837-192.168.67.129-1432812314738
15/05/28 16:55:14 INFO common.Storage: Storage directory /tmp/hadoop-hduser/dfs/name has been successfully formatted.

************************************************************/

Comment: But i am getting this message 15/05/28 16:57:43 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
put: file /test/TestEmp.txt_COPYING_ on client 127.0.0.1.

Comment: If you are seeing test folder (as you say in your third comment) after doing `hdfs dfs -ls /`, there is nothing wrong, your folder is there, and the warning it's not strictly related to the copy command. Maybe you didn't look carefully in the first place, right? The only strange thing it's the **group** of your user, should be **hadoop group**.

Comment: ya,so how to check my group plz

Comment: what message/output you are getting after doing `hdfs dfs -ls /test/`

Comment: hduser@ubuntu:~$ hdfs dfs -ls /test/
15/05/28 17:27:00 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable

Comment: Are you getting this much error only?

Comment: ya its a warning and there is nothing inside /test thats why its show noyhing right?

Comment: still not getting any success  :(

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have `/test` folder in HDFS:

```
hadoop fs -ls /
```

**(OPTIONAL):** If you dont have test folder in HDFS, create it using:

```
hadoop fs -mkdir /test
```

**Check file permission on local filesystem:**

```
ls -l /home/hduser/TestEmp.txt
```

**If the file is not owned by hadoop user, change its ownership:**

```
sudo chown hadoopusername:hadoopgroupname /home/hduser/TestEmp.txt
sudo chmod 777 /home/hduser/TestEmp.txt
```

**Copy file into HDFS:**

```
hadoop fs -copyFromLocal /home/hduser/TestEmp.txt  /test/
```

or use `put` command:

```
hadoop fs -put /home/hduser/TestEmp.txt  /test/
```

Comment: -rwxrwxrwx 1 hduser hadoop 60 May 28 13:05 /home/hduser/TestEmp.txt

Comment: If `hduser` is your hadoop user, no need to change file ownership. Just try to use `-put` command. Could you post the result for `hadoop fs -ls /test`?

Comment: drwxr-xr-x   - hduser supergroup          0 2015-05-28 16:13 /test

Comment: i am getting this message only when i run this hadoop fs -put /home/hduser/TestEmp.txt  /test/                                                                             15/05/28 16:14:21 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
put: file /test/TestEmp.txt._COPYING_ on client 127.0.0.1.

Comment: Could you post your `namenode` log in your question?

Comment: i am new in hadoop , didn't find any namenode logs there.

Comment: You can find your `namenode` logs in `$HADOOP_HOME/logs` folder. Just post the content of the file named as `*-namenode*.log`.

Comment: ok , i found in hdfs-site replication factor was 0 , i made it 1 .now am getting different error during copying file,it say,put: File /test/test.txt._COPYING_ could only be replicated to 0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1).  There are 1 datanode(s) running and no node(s) are excluded in this operation.